# Laravel `with` issues

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.3, eager-loading

I've got 3 models defined as such:

```
class Driver extends Model
{
    public function provider(){
        return $this->belongsTo(Provider::class);
    }
}

class DriverPhone extends Model
{
    public function provider(){
        return $this->belongsTo(Provider::class);
    }
}

class Provider extends Model
{
    public function drivers(){
        return $this->hasMany(Driver::class);
    }

    public function driverPhones(){
        return $this->hasMany(DriverPhone::class);
    }

}
```

Now - I want to get all available `Driver`s, whose `Provider` `DriverPhone`s meet given criteria. I thought that doing it this way would be the way to go:

```
Driver::with(['provider.driverPhones' => function($query) use ($phone_uuid){
    $query->where('uuid', $phone_uuid);
}]);
```

And when I analyse the query via:

```
var_dump($phone_uuid, Driver::with(['provider.driverPhones' => function($query) use ($phone_uuid){
    $query->where('uuid', $phone_uuid);
}])->toSql()); exit;
```

it gives me:

```
select * from `drivers` where `drivers`.`deleted_at` is null
```

Yet when I use `whereHas` the resultset is correct:

```
Driver::whereHas('provider.driverPhones', function($query) use ($phone_uuid){
   $query->where('uuid', $phone_uuid);
})->get()`
```

Am I missing something?

---

Followup question - for given additional models:

```
class Journey extends Model
{
    public function coach(){
         return $this->belongsTo(CoachId::class);
    }
}

class Coach extends Model
{
    public function journey(){
         return $this->belongsTo(Journey::class);
    }
}
```

If I search `Journey::with('coach', 'journeyLocations')->whereHas('coach', [my subquery])` it finds correct `Journey`, but trying to access `coach` gives me null. If I omit `with`, proper `coach` property is accessed, but of course multiple queries are run.

So - what's the deal with `with`?

Comment: Try using a combination of `with()` and `whereHas()` that uses the same subquery `$query->where('uuid', $phone_uuid);` and see if that returns the desired query results.

Comment: @TimLewis - I'm sorry but I don't understand; I thought I was using the same subquery

Comment: Your query should be `Driver::with(...)->whereHas(...)->get();`, with both the `->with()` and `->whereHas()` using the same subquery. I don't see that in your question; only an instance using `->with()` and an instance using `->whereHas()`. Maybe edit your final query into the question, it's possible I'm reading this wrong.

Comment: @TimLewis - I was under the impression that `with` includes all the relationships (using join) so that only one query is being run (and then relationship models are being constructed from the result of one query), whereas `whereHas` does a subquery, effectively running two.

Comment: I thought so at first too, but anytime I've wanted to constrain my original query with a `whereHas()` and include the relationship with a `->with()` I've had to use both to accomplish this. Give it a try and inspect the results with a `dd()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First let me suggest a nicer way to inspect your sql queries:

- Add `\DB::listen(function ($q) { \Log::info($q->sql, $q->bindings); });` before the queries.
- In command line, run `tail -f storage/logs/laravel.log` to see the queries printed there as they are executed.

You will find that actually `with` doesn't do a JOIN. Instead, it looks for related models with a WHERE clause: `WHERE id IN (1, 2, 3)`. It's not a join, it's a separate query.

On the other hand, `whereHas` does include the constraint in the same query, with a WHERE EXISTS clause. So it "filters" from the result, but doesn't provide the eager loading of the related models.

So the solution would be what Tim Lewis mentioned in the comments: apply the same constraint function to `with` and `whereHas`:

```
$constraint = function ($query) use ($phone_uuid) {
    $query->where('uuid', $phone_uuid);
};

Driver::with(['provider.driverPhones' => $constraint])
    ->whereHas('provider.driverPhones', $constraint)
    ->get();
```

Comment: Excellent - thank you very much for this way of checking the queries. It appears my `Coach`es had wrong foreign key set and that was to blame (as `whereHas` does `=` check, which returns true for `3129 = 0101A` and `with` does `IN` check which doesn't).